# How to use pandas read_csv in this situation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data that looks like this

```
id,receiver_id,date,name,age
123,"a,b,c",2012-03-05,"john",32
456,"x,y,z",2012-06-05,"max",49
789,"abc",2012-07-05,"sam",19
```

In a nutshell, the delimiter is a comma (,). However, in case where a particular field is
surrounded with quotes, there might be comma within the value

Comment: `read_csv` should handle this perfectly fine. What do you want the desired output to look like?

Comment: Turns out it was not the read_csv but a custom wrapper around it that was causing the issue. But yeah, read_csv was perfectly adequate